# How to rename voice recorded file before saving it to gallery

Tags: android

This is how i am saving voice recorded file to SDcard,Here want to give rename option for user before saving to gallery,not getting any idea ,Suggest me any solution,Thanks.

```
   protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the above method you posted will get called once the recording is done, What I suggest you do is, show the user a `Dialog` requesting for the name of the file he/she wishes to enter and have this method called on the click of positive button of this `Dialog` also passing this method a `String` parameter denoting the filename; something like this `protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary(String fileName) {`. Set this filename `values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, fileName);` like this.